# Apply 1D Torque to 3D Revolute Joint without back reaction

Tags: modelica, dymola, openmodelica

the model is as simple as this: I'd like to apply a torque to the Rotational Flange of a Revolute Joint.
However, the torque reaction should **not** be applied to the Support Flange of the Revolute Joint.
The torque reaction is indeed counterbalanced **elsewhere** and not in the Revolute Joint itself.
A real-world example is a vehicle wheel: the torque is given by a powertrain and transferred to the wheel by a shaft, so the torque reaction is not perceived on the wheelhub but on the powertrain mounts.
[image]

So, none of the above seems to be correct:

- in BLUE: there is a reaction on the Revolute frame_a that there shoudn't be. The support (white circle) seems to always balance the torque applied to the flange (gray circle)) but it doesn't make sense in this case;
- in RED: there is no reaction on Revolute frame_a but there is no speed in the 1D line and this is not ok.

So, how can apply a Torque to a Revolute Joint without being forced to sense the counterbalanced torque directly on the joint?

[Here the code](https://snippet.host/zhbo)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't belong here

Comment: @Graviton I'll be glad to move it where it belongs. Can you tell me a better place?

Comment: I asume that @Graviton wants to see this issue in https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaStandardLibrary. And yes, I also wondered, why the rotational axis of the revolute joint are implemented the way they are and not symmetically.

Comment: Now available as https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaStandardLibrary/issues/3761

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with this solution that requires modifying the Revolute joint.
[This is a minimal library with the modified Revolute Joint and a minimal example](https://snippet.host/hyhn)

Basically I just required that the torque on frame_a and frame_b is equal *only along two directions orthogonal to the revolute axis* (before they were equal along any direction).
And the torque called 'tau' provided by the auxiliary flange is applied along revolute axis direction only to frame_b, while for frame_a along this direction the torque is imposed to be zero.

This makes much more sense to me, but I'll be glad if someone proves me wrong.

As @tbeu just saw, I also [sent an issue to the Modelica Standard Library GitHub](https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaStandardLibrary/issues/3761), so it might be worth to wait for some official answer.